# Ruby on Rails - bundler command not recognized after install on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just installed Ruby 1.8.7 on Windows 7 and the shell recognizes the ruby command, but not when I try to run `bundle install`

Is that common or expected? How do I get the bundler to work?

Thanks!

Comment: `gem install bundler`

Comment: @jdoe that worked thank you. Going to upvote you in some other posts of yours. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure the bundler gem is installed. It might not be included in your ruby distribution

```
gem install bundler
```